# Changing font size for chapter title and number

Tags: fontsize

I want to change the font size for the chapter title and chapter number.

My code in part is as below.

I want the font for the chapter to be greater than the one achieved through `\Huge`. Is there any way to do that for the document class I am using?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.81cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapternumberfont{\Huge} 
\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{300}{250}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{14}{17}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{12}{14}}
\chaptertitlefont{\Huge}
```

My current font size looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`\fontsize{<size>}{<baseline skip>}` should be followed by `\selectfont` in order to select the font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{sectsty,lmodern}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

Lorem ipsum \ldots

\chapternumberfont{\fontsize{35pt}{32pt}\selectfont}
\chaptertitlefont{\fontsize{38pt}{35pt}\selectfont}

\chapter{A chapter}

Lorem ipsum \ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is meant by `baseline skip`? Is it the left margin?

Comment: @xxx---: No. A baseline skip is the vertical length between the baseline of two horizontal pieces of text... like two lines of a paragraph. `<size>` is (should be) smaller than `<baseline skip>` otherwise the lines within a paragraph will have virtually no space between them. Check out the difference between `\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont\lipsum[1]` and `\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont\lipsum[1]` yourself ([code](https://pastebin.com/raw/Yuwg8pfy); [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIDS3.png)).